# Is Ethernet PoE direct burial safe in a submerged implementation?

Tags: ethernet, power-over-ethernet

Situation... Need to power a Raspberry Pi 3B+ on a Purple Martin birdhouse pole mounted

*** IN A LAKE ***, 15 feet from shore.

Current intent is to use conduit to enclose the Cat-5e (direct burial type)  cable running underwater to and up the pole.
The Cat-5 cable will be  "Underground Direct Burial" type cable, and providing PoE for running the Raspberry Pi.

So, my question is, in the worst case situation where the Cat5e cable some how becomes cut or exposed underwater, will power from the PoE function create an electrocution hazard to someone in the water?

I want to make 100% sure I'm not creating a potential hazard should the Cat5e with PoE become exposed.
FYI, wiring and conduit would be removed each year at the end of the season.

TLDR: Could someone get electrocuted by PoE cable being exposed underwater?
Is it safe to run Ethernet PoE cable underwater?

Alternatively, if you can recommend a better solution (Cat6e direct burial in a conduit?) that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SuperUser :-)

Check out Wikipedia's [PoE-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet). An exposed wire will give a jolt, but those are hardly fatal values. The cable category affects speeds, not the amount of PoE power.

You will obviously need to protect the wire. You should choose cable that's intended for underwater usage. Belden has a nice [article](https://www.belden.com/blogs/direct-burial-cable-your-questions-answered) discussing direct burial cable. I would still run it through a flex tube, it doesn't add much to the cost or make the installation more difficult, but does add another protective layer. The cable reseller can best advise on this.

Another option would be creating a wireless bridge between the pole and the shoreline, but you'd still need to pull power to the pole, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: A read of https://www.belden.com/blogs/direct-burial-cable-your-questions-answered implies dirct burial cable is designed to survive long-term contact with water.

Comment: Heh I just closed that page literally 30 sec before your comment and was going to update my answer :-D I'm on the "let's err to the side of caution" -crowd. I'd still run the wire through flex tube, it doesn't add much to the cost or trouble but does add protection.